# Turn based chat program in c

Tags: c, file

I'm currently writing a chat program in C. It operates in two terminals, and uses one program. A sample input of session 1 would look like:

```
./a.out a.txt b.txt Phil
```

Where a.txt is the file to be used for input/reading, and b.txt is the file to be used for output/sending a message. Phil is the chat handle.
It follows that the input of session 2 looks like:

```
./a.out b.txt a.txt Jill
```

So that the input file is the output file of the first session, enabling the chat to work, and for the two terminals to talk to each other.

A sample run of this program would look something like:

```
Send:    Are you there?
Received [Jill]: Yup!
Send:    Okay see ya!
Received [Jill]: Bye!
^C
```

And vice versa in the other terminal. However, I'm having trouble getting my program to send the files and receive them automatically. My output looks correct, but I can only receive a message if I send one, which sort of defeats the purpose of the chat. My question is, where in my while loop am I going wrong, to where I have to send a message before I can read the one the other session has sent? Here is the code I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {

    // Initialize file variables
    FILE *in;
    FILE *out;

    // Initialize incoming, incoming check, and outgoing variables
    char inc[300] = " ";
    char incCheck[300] = " ";
    char send[300];
    char handle[300];
    int size, counter;
    counter=1;
    // This checks if a user has already entered a message
    // i.e. entered the chat
    if (in = fopen(argv[1], "r")) {
        fclose(in);
    }
    else {
        // create an empty in.txt to bypass segfault if the file doesn't already exist
        in = fopen(argv[1], "w");
        fclose(in);

    // To check if anything has been received yet.
        if (strcmp(inc, incCheck) == 0) {
         printf("Nothing has been received yet.\n");
        }
    }   
    // The while loop that reads and writes the files
    while(1) {

        // Read the incoming file and put it to a string
        // It will read the incoming file over and over until a message is seen
        in = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        fgets(inc, size, in);
        fclose(in);

        // This counter is only for the first message, since it is not possible 
        // that one has already been received.
    if (counter > 0) {
        size=sizeof(send);
        printf("Send: \t");
        fgets(send, size, stdin);
        out = fopen(argv[2], "w");
        fprintf(out, "%s",send);
        fclose(out);
        counter=0;
    }

        // If the incoming file is different, print it out
    if (strcmp(inc, incCheck) != 0) {
        printf("Received [%s]: %s", argv[3], inc);

        in = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        fgets(inc, size, in);
        strcpy(incCheck, inc);
        fclose(in);
        // And prompt to send another message.
        size=sizeof(send);
        printf("Send: \t");
        fgets(send, size, stdin);
        out = fopen(argv[2], "w");
        fprintf(out, "%s",send);
        fclose(out);

        in = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        fgets(inc, size, in);
        fclose(in);

        }
    }
```

Comment: When was the last time you noticed anybody chatting through terminals?  Is this a homework assignment?  What *exactly* was the teacher's assignment?

Comment: This is homework. We're required to write a C program that implements a turn-based chat system. "Chat user interactions
occur as terminal I/O and data is passed between chat processes as plain-text files. Only plain-text file
I/O can be used to communicate the chat messages, you cannot use networking or other system calls."

Answer (score 0):

Setting one side of the chat as initiator solves the problem. Is that sufficient ? In code below this is solved by setting one of the handles as "s".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {

    // Initialize file variables
    FILE *in;
    FILE *out;

    // Initialize incoming, incoming check, and outgoing variables
     char inc[300] = " ";
    char incCheck[300] = " ";
    char send[300];
    char oldsend[300];
    char handle[300];
    int size, counter;
    counter=1;
    // This checks if a user has already entered a message
    // i.e. entered the chat
    if (in = fopen(argv[1], "r")) {
            fclose(in);
    }
    else {
            // create an empty in.txt to bypass segfault if the file    doesn't already exist
            in = fopen(argv[1], "w");
            fclose(in);

    // To check if anything has been received yet.
            if (strcmp(inc, incCheck) == 0) {
             printf("Nothing has been received yet.\n");
            }
    }   
        in = fopen(argv[1], "r");
            fgets(incCheck, size, in);
            fclose(in);
    in = fopen(argv[2], "r");
            fgets(oldsend, size, in);
            fclose(in);

    // The while loop that reads and writes the files
    while(1) {

            // Read the incoming file and put it to a string
            // It will read the incoming file over and over until a message is seen

            // This counter is only for the first message, since it is not possible 
            // that one has already been received.
    if ((counter > 0) && ( strcmp(argv[3],"s")==0)) {
        size=sizeof(send);
        do {
    printf("Send: \t");
    fgets(send, size, stdin);
        }while (strcmp(send, oldsend)==0);
        strcpy (oldsend,send);
        out = fopen(argv[2], "w");
        fprintf(out, "%s",send);
        fclose(out);
        counter=0;
 }
 in = fopen(argv[1], "r");
            fgets(inc, size, in);
            fclose(in);
 }

            // If the incoming file is different, print it out
    if (strcmp(inc, incCheck) != 0) {
 printf("Received [%s]: %s", argv[3], inc);

            in = fopen(argv[1], "r");
            fgets(inc, size, in);
            strcpy(incCheck, inc);
            fclose(in);
            // And prompt to send another message.
            size=sizeof(send);
 do {
            printf("Answer: \t");
            fgets(send, size, stdin);
 } while (strcmp(send, oldsend)==0);
            strcpy (oldsend,send);
            out = fopen(argv[2], "w");
            fprintf(out, "%s",send);
            fclose(out);
            }
    }
    return 0;
}
```